# Kubernetes clean up failed containers

Tags: kubernetes

Is Kubernetes taking care of cleaning up failed/stopped containers at some point?

It doesn't seem like it and it can pile up.

I know how to clean them up manually but i wonder if there is a setting to automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to first check the [docs site](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/garbage-collection.html) before posting a question. Kubernetes does handle container GC, quoting from the docs page:

We also allow users to customize garbage collection policy, basically 
via following three flags.

- minimum-container-ttl-duration, minimum age for a finished container before it is garbage collected. Default is 1 minute.
- maximum-dead-containers-per-container, maximum number of old instances to retain per container. Default is 2.
- maximum-dead-containers, maximum number of old instances of containers to retain globally. Default is 100.

Comment: I felt the terms used in Kubernetes document is not easy to understand. I appreciate this question